# Saving and loading with Json

Tags: json, libgdx

Until now I was using serializable for saving and loading data, but now I have switched to JSON. And as soon as I have started there is a problem. Json will not save me any class. I was trying to save standalone Variables.class. This class contains various static data - player type string, bonus type strings, scores. Then I did create private class in class, then class in method, but nothing. Output od `System.out.println(json)` is always just `{}`.

For example this was my last attempt to make things work:

```
public static void saveAVD() {
    Variables v = new Variables();
    String json = new Json().toJson(v);
    System.out.println(json);
    file.writeString(json.prettyPrint(json), false);
}
```

**Note:** File variable is located in local bin folder. Inside that file are also just two empty bracelets `({})`

Any advice?

Comment: Use the `Gson` library and move on with your life. It's awesome.

Comment: Can you show some of the content of Variables?  It sounds like the properties are `static`?  JSON probably only saves instance variables.

Comment: It does not save static variables by default. You need to implement your own `Serializer` which will also write the static fields to JSON.

Comment: That is probably the case. All variables in Variables.class are static. Now am having some success with adding all variables to Arraylist as objects. It still needs some testin though but it seems to be ok. Thanks for repy P.T. and noone. I will check how to approach this problem when i will complete Arraylist to JSON task

Answer (score 1):

(Credit to noone, who answered this in a comment).

JSON will, by default, not serialize static fields.  The quickest way to get the behavior you want would probably be to convert the Variables class into a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: Thy for answer. Well i found some easier way and i have put all static data in array and i save just that. It is working and its relatively simple. But i will check that singleton classes

Comment: Design-wise, keeping an array of things that need to be saved is probably better.  The singleton was just the most direct conversion.